# Different sums counter of a given set

Tags: python, subset, combinations

I am working on this code (credits to Shreyanshi Arun for the base code) that prints the sums of all subsets of a given set:

```
def subsetSums(arr, l, r, sum=0):
    # Print current subset
    if l > r:
        global k
        print(sum,end=" ")
        k += 1
        return

    # Subset including arr[l]
    subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum + arr[l])

    # Subset excluding arr[l]
    subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum)

k = 0
arr = [0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 5]
n = len(arr)

subsetSums(arr, 0, n - 1)

print ("\n Combinations:",k)
```

I am trying to adapt it to receive a **count** of how many sums are possible. As I left the code, the variable k serves as the sum counter. However, I would like this counter to increase **only** when the resulting sum is not equal to any previous one.

For example, in this code, the result is like this:

```
19.0 14.0 14.0 9.0 16.0 11.0 11.0 6.0 17.0 12.0 12.0 [...]
Combinations: 256
```

As one can see, the second and third results are 14.0, for example. In these cases, I want to avoid k being increased, as the third sum is equal to the second one. Otherwise, all my combinations are going to result in 256 (for arrays of length 8). The same condition should apply to any upcoming repeated number in the array, not just directly consequent numbers.

Comment: may be try adding result to the set then you can use length of set as number of combinations

Answer (score 2):

Create a set to hold all the sums. Add each sum to the set, and at the end the length of the set will be the number of different sums.

```
def subsetSums(arr, l, r, sum=0, allSums = None):
    if allSums is None:
        allSums = set()
    # Print current subset
    if l > r:
        allSums.add(sum)
        print(sum,end=" ")
        return len(allSums)

    # Subset including arr[l]
    subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum + arr[l], allSums)

    # Subset excluding arr[l]
    return subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum, allSums)

arr = [0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 5]
n = len(arr)

k = subsetSums(arr, 0, n - 1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of still going through all 2<sup>n</sup> subsets, I'd just build the set of sums like this:

```
sums = {0}
for x in arr:
    sums |= {s + x for s in sums}
print(len(sums))
```

Or with `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> len(reduce(lambda sums, x: sums | {s + x for s in sums}, arr, {0}))
39
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach here could be maintaining a hash-table to check for already appeared sums

```
def subsetSums(arr, l, r,sum=0):
# Print current subset
if l > r:
    global k
    global sumHash
    print(sum, end=" ")
    if(sum not in sumHash):
        k += 1
    sumHash[sum] = True
    return

# Subset including arr[l]
subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r,sum + arr[l])

# Subset excluding arr[l]
subsetSums(arr, l + 1, r, sum)


k = 0
sumHash = dict()
arr = [0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 5]
n = len(arr)

subsetSums(arr, 0, n - 1)

print("\n Combinations:", k)
```